# When will the last total solar eclipse occur?

Tags: the-moon, solar-eclipse

Because the moon distance from earth grows, how long will it take, that it is no longer possible to see a total eclipse but only circular eclipses? And does it make a difference if you are on the mount everest or on sea level?

Comment: About 600 million years.

Comment: @PM2Ring is that back of the envelope or is there a source available? Since it matches the [posted answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/29246/7982) nicely, it would be cool to know.

Comment: @uhoh That info comes from Richard Vondrak of NASA's GSFC. I found it at https://www.google.com.au/amp/s/amp.space.com/37627-total-solar-eclipse-earth-moon-alignment-future.html

Comment: @PM2Ring thanks! btw I'm curious, what is google.com/amp/...?

Comment: @PM2Ring okay I see, thanks!  (https://www.space.com/37627-total-solar-eclipse-earth-moon-alignment-future.html)

Comment: **This is not a duplicate.** That whole thing is about the definition of transits, and the answer is 10 Tyr  or 1E+13 years. The answer her 8E+08 years, a factor of 10,000 longer. @PM2Ring has also independently mentioned 6E+08 years. That answer does not answer this question, not even close!

Comment: @CarlWitthoft these are very different questions. By closing, you send people to the wrong answer to this question.

Comment: @uhoh I think the questions are similar in principle. Grimaldi made a reasonable but arbitrary decision about what the angular diameter of the Moon needs to be so that its transit of the Sun doesn't qualify as an eclipse. But the 10 trillion years he calculates isn't really valid. The Sun will be a white dwarf *long* before then, and the Earth-Moon system will have suffered major disruption during the Sun's red giant phase, and will most likely get swallowed at some stage.

Comment: @Carl If there's any dupe-closing to be done, I'm inclined to go in the other direction, closing coblr's old question as a dupe of this new one.

Comment: You have an answer to this question here: https://www.skyandtelescope.com/astronomy-resources/astronomy-questions-answers/when-will-the-last-total-solar-eclipse-occur and here: https://www.space.com/37627-total-solar-eclipse-earth-moon-alignment-future.html.

Answer (score 9):

I will take a stab at it.  Assuming

- the last eclipse happens when the moon is at perigee and the earth is at aphelion.
- the moon's perigee is increasing by 4 cm per year,
- the earth's aphelion does not change with time,
- the sun and the moon are perfect spheres,
- the radius of the sun and moon don't change, and
- a total eclipse occurs when $r_{\mathrm{sun}}/d_{\mathrm{sun}} < r_{\mathrm{moon}}/d_{\mathrm{moon}}$ where $r$ is radius and $d$ is distance,

I get the following results:

- The last total eclipse at sea level will occur in 721,587,917 years at sea
  level  (obviously too many significant digits).
- The last total eclipse at mount Everest will occur in 721,807,917 years.
- The difference is 220,000 years = (height_of_Everest) * 25000 years/km.

Mathematica Source Code:

```
dSun = 152097000; rSun = 695508; dMoonNow = 357347; rMoon = 1737; 
rEarth = 6371; hEverest = 8 + 8/10;
sol2 = Solve[ rMoon/(d + t 4/100/1000) == rSun/(dSun - rEarth), t][[1]];
Print[ t /. sol2 /. d -> dMoonNow - rEarth  // Round];
Print[ t /. sol2 /. d -> dMoonNow - rEarth - hEverest // Round];
```

Comment: Over that time scale and to that level of precision, will the Sun's diameter change as it evolves?

Comment: I think so!   (I added the assumption that it stays constant.)

Comment: The Sun will get larger by  2-3% on that timescale. So this answer would be an upper limit.

Comment: But since the apparent size of the Moon shrinks by 8% in the same time, I would guestimate that the overestimate of the time is only by about 25%.

Comment: There are several things wrong with this answer. (1) "The moon's perigee is increasing by 4 cm per year." That is the current rate, and it is abnormally high, thanks to the Americas, Afro-eurasia, both of which block equatorial tidal flow, and due to the shape of the North Atlantic, whose shape resonates with the M2 tide. A better figure is less than 2 cm per year. (2) "The earth's aphelion does not change with time." It most certainly does. The key reason we are not seeing an ice stage starting now is because the Earth's eccentricity is very low. (Continued)

Comment: (3) "The radius of the sun and moon don't change." The Sun's radius increases as it ages. When one takes all of these into consideration, the correct answer is somewhere between a few hundred million years to over two billion years.

Comment: @DavidHammen: question: 4cm/year, trivially projected back, would mean the moon formed ~180,000 km above the earth (half way, sotosay). Would that be consistent with the Theia hypothesis ?

Comment: @a_donda - No, it is not. A constant rate is ludicrous. Tidal friction suggests the recession rate falls extremely rapidly with distance. (Tidal heating of a moon is proportional to $r^{-15/2}$). This is in fact an argument used by young earth creationists. (Know thine enemy.) The problem with these YEC arguments is that the current lunar rate is known to be anomalously high. Tidal rhythmites show that the lunar recession rate was less than half the current rate half for almost all of the last 2.5 billion years. (Continued)

Comment: Why 2.5 billion years? It's hard to find rock that show signs of tides that are older than 2.5 billion years. This raises a question: Despite the current distance between the Earth and Moon being larger than it was in the past, why is the current lunar recession rate so large? The answer lies in the shape of the continents and the shape of the oceans, particularly the North Atlantic.

Comment: Projecting the current value of 4 cm/year (better: 3.8 cm/yr) forward is equally incorrect, for two reasons. One is that the recession rate should naturally drop as the Moon recedes, even if the North Atlantic holds its shape. A constant rate is inconsistent with physics. The other is that plate tectonics will eventually reshape the North Atlantic so that it is not nearly as good a damped resonator with regard to the M2 tidal constituent as it is now. The lunar recession rate will drop precipitously somewhere in the next 721 million years.

Comment: In principle I too think "No, it is not" is correct, that's why I asked: recession rate must have been much higher if we speculate that the moon formed above but close to the roche limit. I find it as reasonable or unreasonable to use 2cm/yr, 4cm/yr, or even more, and so side with the ~600My figure. FWIW these guys suggest moon's recession may be increasing over the past 1.4By: https://www.pnas.org/content/115/25/6363, which are unrelated to today's continental arrangements. Uncertainties ....